# SSH tunnel prevents my spawned script from exiting

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm executing a bash script in Node.js like this:

```
const script = child_process.spawn('local_script.sh');

const stdout = fs.createWriteStream('stdout');
const stderr = fs.createWriteStream('stderr');

script.stdout.pipe(stdout);
script.stderr.pipe(stderr);

script.on('close', function(code) {
  console.log('Script exited with code', code);
});
```

My `local_script.sh` uploads a script to my remote server and executes it:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/root/remote_script.sh
HOST=123.456.78.9

scp remote_script.sh root@${HOST}:${FILE}
ssh root@${HOST} bash ${FILE}
```

Finally, my `remote_script.sh` is supposed to open an SSH tunnel (and perform some other actions that are not relevant for this question):

```
#!/bin/bash

REDIS_HOST=318.353.31.3

ssh -f -n root@${REDIS_HOST} -L 6379:127.0.0.1:6379 -N &
```

The problem is that even though I'm opening the SSH tunnel in the background, it seems my `remote_script.sh` never exits, because the Node.js `close` event is never called. If I *don't* open the SSH tunnel, it exits and emits the event as expected.

How can I make sure the script exits cleanly after opening the SSH tunnel? Note that I want the tunnel to persist after the script finishes.

Comment: Can you try `ssh -f -n root@${HOST} bash ${FILE}`

Comment: That didn't do it, but `ssh -f root@${HOST} bash ${FILE} >/dev/null 2>&1` did! However, now obviously my node process isn't receiving the output from `remote_script.sh`. I could redirect it to my log files instead, but I would like to understand why my script doesn't exit if I don't redirect the output.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but my guess is that the backgrounded ssh session (remote -> REDIS) is keeping the remote tty alive, and thus preventing the local -> remote session from closing. Try changing remote_script.sh to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

redis_host=318.353.31.3

nohup ssh -f -n "root@${redis_host}" -L 6379:127.0.0.1:6379 -N >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

BTW, note that I switched the variable name to lowercase; there are a number of all-caps variables with special meanings (including `HOST`), and re-using any of them can have weird effects, so lower- or mixed-case variables are preferred for script use. Also, I double-quoted the variable reference, which won't matter in this case but is a good general habit for those cases where it does matter.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately... but thanks for the tip. I'm relatively new to bash scripting so I appreciate all help or advice.

Comment: I managed to 'solve' the problem by doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707658/ssh-tunnel-prevents-my-spawned-script-from-exiting#comment105570090_59707658 does that give you any clue as to why the problem occurred in the first place?

Comment: @Rits Not really; all that's doing is letting the local script finish while the ssh session continues running in the background. It doesn't answer the question of how to get the script on the remote host to exit. Can you try interactively sshing into the remote host, run remote_script.sh by hand, and see what it does?

Comment: It sets up the ssh tunnel and exits the script.

Comment: OK, using your version of `remote_script.sh` with nohup, if I run `local_script.sh` directly, it does exit cleanly, but the ssh tunnel doesn't seem to persist beyond completion of the script. If I run `remote_script.sh` directly on the remote host, the ssh tunnel does persist and the script exits cleanly, but then it hangs when I try to logout.

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to solve it is by using `ssh -a root${HOST} bash ${FILE}` in my `local_script.sh`. Note the `-a` flag which **disables my forwarding ssh agent**.

The important clue was that when I ran `remote_script.sh` on my remote machine directly, it would do everything as expected including a clean exit, but when I would try to logout, that's where it would hang.

Apparently ssh doesn't want to terminate while there are still active connections. When I typed `~#`, which shows active ssh connections, it did indeed show my forwarding ssh agent.